# Dynalically Adding AddHeadersToRequests values in Ocelot in Dotnetcore 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, ocelot

ApiGateway was implemented In Dotnetcore6.0. using Ocelot.

In the Ocelot config file DownstreamPathTemplate having the UpstreamHeaderTransform. This header values need to add dynamically. ApiGateway application not using any authuntication. No claims information is available.

```
  "UpstreamHeaderTransform": {
    "key": "xxx"
  },
```

The key value should be added in Middleware or any other place dynamically. Any possible way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try via MiddleWare:

```
public class CustomMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        DownstreamRequest downstreamRequest = context.Items.DownstreamRequest();
        downstreamRequest.Headers.Add("X-CustomHeader", "value");
        ...
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer should be considered as it solves the problems